# how to delete multiple lines from Microsoft word

Tags: ms-word

My word file contain some data which are following

```
product/productId: 0784010927
review/userId: A19V0VJMKKRMC8
review/profileName: jj "Justin"
review/helpfulness: 1/1
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1031961600
review/summary: one of my all tyime faves
review/text: i am from this genration which makes me different because i like movies from the 80s.  well this is a must see.

product/productId: 0784010927
review/userId: A3OZU2EMJQ5FIC
review/profileName: danielle levin
review/helpfulness: 1/1
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1022025600
review/summary: The Best in the world
review/text: This movie has touched me so much it's great. The movie is about a a young girl who is a little daddy girl and does everything she is told until she met her love Johnny (Patrick Swayze). Baby (Jennifer Grey) learns not only how to dance
```

**But I want to delete the portion of line which starting with review\text from every paragraph. my output should be like that**

```
product/productId: 0784010927
review/userId: A3OZU2EMJQ5FIC
review/profileName: danielle levin
review/helpfulness: 1/1
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1022025600
review/summary: The Best in the world
```

Any one can help me please with any idea using macro in Microsoft word or any other solutions.

Comment: You can use [POI Word](https://poi.apache.org/document/). It's a Java API to manipulate word files.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub Demo()
      With Selection.Find
        While .Execute(FindText:="review/text", Forward:=True)
          If .Found = True Then
            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.TypeBackspace
          End If
        Wend
      End With
End Sub
```

Make sure you keep your cursor at the starting position of the document.

Comment: @MohammadHasan: Consider accepting the answer so that community can know that this is working solution.